# finding friends in a rails app via facebook, gmail, twitter, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, gmail

I have built a social networking app in rails, and am looking for a simple way to allow users to login to their various other accounts (OAuth?) such as facebook, twitter, gmail, other mail clients, etc and see if their friends/contacts on those sites are signed up for my site.

Additionally I will be adding functionality to allow users to invite their non-signed up friends to my site via these same sites.

In the future I will also want to make it so that users can post their submissions on my site to these various other sites.

At this moment though, the most important feature is enabling users to see which of their contacts on these other sites are signed up for my site.

What is the best way to go about this? What gems should I be looking for (OAuth, RFacebook, Facebooker, etc).

I am currently using restful authentication (Also, can someone point me in the direction of a question that answers how to allow users to sign in, using restful authentication, using their username OR their email?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been ages since this was posted, but I felt it might be relevant to anyone who happens upon this question, the best way to do this is using the https://github.com/intridea/omniauth gem.

For invites you should take a look at https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts.

Also, if you are using a newer version of Rails and devise then you should check out this screen cast by Ryan Bates on using omniauth with Devise http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised.

Comment: +1 from me for giving a better answer than my (previously accepted) one

Answer (score 2):

I used omniauth gem for oauth authentication and then
used fb_graph to fetch friend list from facebook.
And i guess contact gem would help pulling friends from gmail, ymail and etc.

Comment: @chaitanyasaraf you can use the same omniauth gem for twitter also. here it is, https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that each service has its own API and it will be up to you to connect your application individually to each service.

Here are the API docs for [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/), [Twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) and [GMail](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/)

Just Google `"<Site name> API"`