# how to create a feature to "find people via gmail , facebook" to my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, gmail

I'm developing a website that is a social network where people can add their friends to it and interact with them, I want to help them find their friends via *Gmail* or *Facebook* to make it easier for them.

Please help me with where can I find instructions to get it done.

thanks.
(I'm not a very experienced developer so if you need me to supply more info just let me know)

Comment: I remember this question has already been closed some days ago

Comment: Been asked so many times before you, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220589/importing-gmail-yahoo-hotmail-aol-address-book-with-rails) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579575/finding-friends-in-a-rails-app-via-facebook-gmail-twitter-etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Gmail: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/